# Is there a way to cap the max size on a STL::map container?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, size, max

My application can only process up to a certain number of entry in the map structure, how do I specify that limit in my code so that my code does not get overwhelmed (for lack of better term).  Is there a way to specify the max limit when defining the variable of type map?

Thanks

Comment: Other than not putting more than N elements into the map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to set a limit when instantiating the map, though I supposed you could have your own safe guard when accessing it. For example:

```
if (mymap.find(a) == mymap.end() and mymap.size() >= MAX_MAP_ALLOWED) {
    throw (runtime_error("map limit exceeded"));
} else {
    mymap[a] = b;
}
```

You could possibly create your own map class that encapsulates these checks.

Answer (score 1):

The stl containers also take an '[allocator](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/alloc.html)' as a (defaulted) parameter.  This allocator is the container's means to allocate new space for it's data.

If you define a 'capped' allocator (sounds simple, hey?), you're there.

EDIT - In some fora, I found that the allocators, though initially intended stateless, can be statefull on most (modern) compilers.  That's why I carry on on this.  It's quite cumbersome, though, to do it this way, and probably way more easy and comprenensible to aggregate your map type in a cappedmap adapter.

It took me a lot of moments here and there, but here I got a compiling, capped, example:

```
// an allocator with maximally MAX elements.
template< typename T, size_t MAX = 5 >
struct AllocateCapped {

    // reuses an existing allocator
    typedef std::allocator<T> tallocator;

    typedef typename tallocator::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename tallocator::pointer pointer;
    typedef typename tallocator::reference reference;
    typedef typename tallocator::const_pointer const_pointer;
    typedef typename tallocator::const_reference const_reference;
    typedef typename tallocator::size_type size_type;
    typedef typename tallocator::difference_type difference_type;
```

The actual code of the capped allocator delegates to the `allocator` member:

```
    size_t free;
    tallocator allocator;

    AllocateCapped():free(MAX){
        printf("capped");
    }

template<typename T2>
    AllocateCapped( const AllocateCapped<T2>& other ){}

    pointer allocate( size_type n, const_pointer hint = 0) {
        if( !free ) throw std::bad_alloc();
        free-=n;
        return allocator.allocate( n, hint );
    }

    void deallocate( pointer p, size_type n ) {
        free+=n;
        allocator.deallocate(p,n);
    }

    size_type max_size() const { return free; }
    void construct( pointer p, const_reference val ) {
        return allocator.construct(p,val);
    }
    void destroy( pointer p ) { allocator.destroy(p); }

    template<class _Other>
    struct rebind 
    {   // convert this type to _ALLOCATOR<_Other>
        typedef typename AllocateCapped<_Other> other;
    };

};
```

This allocator can be used like this:

```
// example structure
struct s {
    int i;
    s():i(){}
    s(int i):i(i){}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
typedef AllocateCapped< std::pair<const int, s> > talloc;
talloc a;
talloc::pointer p = reinterpret_cast<talloc::pointer>( a.allocate(1,0) );
a.construct(p, talloc::value_type() );
a.destroy(p);
a.deallocate(p, 1 );

std::map<int , s, std::less<int>, talloc > m;
std::vector<int, AllocateCapped<int> > v;
for( int i = 0; i != 4; ++i ) {
    m[i]=s(i);
    v.push_back(i);
}
m[5]=s(5); // throws
v.push_back(5); // throws
return 0;
}
```

Note: not thoroughly tested.  It's just an idea.

Comment: Interesting. Would the user have to override `max_size()`?

Comment: Unfortunately, allocators are not per-container, so unless you have a separate allocator type for each instance of the map whose size you want limited, this approach isn't going to work.

Comment: @James:  One could `typedef` a `map` with a special allocator.

Comment: @james: I beg to differ: the `map` constructor I know (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/map) takes an allocator object as parameter.

Comment: @xtofl: It does, but there is a requirement in the Allocator spec that says "All instances of a given allocator type are required to be interchangeable and always compare equal to each other."  Since the allocator instances have to be interchangeable, the container doesn't need to store the allocator you give it; it can just default construct another allocator of the same type (or it can make copies of the allocator and use them or it can make all sorts of other optimizations).

Comment: @John:  FYI, see my previous comment.

Comment: I would delete this answer, but I think it's useful for the future me, having the same idea, to leave it in.  Feel free to downvote (but not too much :) )

Answer (score 1):

After trying out the idea of a capped allocator, I think it's way more straightforward to aggregate an `std::map` (note: not inherit-from!  At least not publicly) in a `cappedadaptor`.

```
template<typename tKey, typename tVal> class cappedmap {
   typedef std::map<tKey,tVal> tmap;
   tmap mymap;

   cappedmap(size_t amax):mymax(amax){}

   // adapt the map interface
   pair<tmap::iterator,bool> insert( tmap::value_type kv ) { 
        if( mymap.size() > mymax ) throw myexcept();
        return mymap.insert(kv);
   }

   tVal operator[]( tKey k ) { 
     tVal v = mymap[k];
     if( mymap.size() > mymax ) { 
        mymap.remove(k)
        throw myexcept();
     }
   }
   ...
};
```